# Add event handlers when extending a view in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I am a backbone.js n00b and am having trouble understanding how to extend a view. I have a basic "item" model and view. I'd like to extend both the model and view to be "specificItem." Is there a way to add events in the extended view rather than just replace them all?

Item View:

```
var itemView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...
   events: {
      "click" : "foo"
      , "dblclick div": "bar"
   }
   ...
});
```

Specific Item View:

```
var specificItemView = itemView.extend({
   ...
   // I'd like this to simply add an event handler not replace the ones defined above
   events: {
      "contextmenu" : "baz"
   }
   ...
});
```

Is it even supported to extend views in this way or can we only do that to models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken extend does not work recursively, but you can do it yourself. I think something like this should work:

```
var specificItemView = itemView.extend({
   ...
   // I'd like this to simply add an event handler not replace the ones defined above
   events: _.extend({
      "contextmenu" : "baz"
   }, itemView.prototype.events),
   ...
});
```

---

[Here is the proof](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L635-643), that extend does not merge recursivly